# JDBC MySQL Сложный запрос с временными таблицами

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

У меня есть сложный запрос в БД MySQL вида:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS allbydate;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE allbydate (INDEX channel (calldate,channel,src,dst)) AS (
select ...
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS allsrc;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE allsrc (INDEX channel (channel,disposition)) AS (
select ...
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alldst;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE alldst (INDEX channel (dstchannel,calldate,disposition)) AS (
select ...
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS result;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result (INDEX channel (calldate,number)) AS (
select * from allsrc
);

INSERT INTO result 
select * from alldst;

select * from result;
```

Последним select'ом я получаю нужные мне данные.
А запрашиваю я строкой типа:

```
Object object = jdbcTemplate.query(query, ROW_MAPPER);
```

, где в query я включаю весь запрос целиком.

Получаю ошибку:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()
```

Я понимаю, что после каждого DROP, CREATE mysql шлет что-то типа:

```
Query OK, 54 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 54  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

И поэтому JDBC не может идентифицировать Object...

Как правильнее поступить в этом случае?

Мне нужно, чтоб JDBC выполнил последовательность команд в рамках одной транзакции, так как я создаю таблицы типа TEMPORARY...

Comment: *Как правильнее поступить в этом случае?* Я бы предложил всё вот это упаковать в хранимую процедуру, и запускать именно её. *Последним select'ом я получаю нужные мне данные.* А предпоследний SELECT - он-то куда девается?

Comment: Предпоследнего нет, как самостоятельного селекта... там конструкция INSERT INTO result 
select * from alldst;
Которая вставляет данные в result

Comment: Пардон, значит, был недостаточно внимателен. Кстати, а версия MySQL случайно не восьмая? если так, то там можно использовать WITH, и никакие временные таблицы вообще не потребуются.

Comment: на досуге посмотрю этот WITH...

Answer (score 1):

В общем решение такое:
Каждый запрос записал в массив

```
String[] query = {"query1","query2",...}
```

Затем по очереди беру из query[i] запрос и исполняю через

```
for (int i = 0; i < query.length-1; i++) {
jdbcTemplate.update(query[i]);
}
Object object = jdbcTemplate.query(query[query.length-1], ROW_MAPPER);
```

т.е. я только результат последнего запроса записываю через ROW_MAPPER